# BSTR to String using W2A

Tags: visual-c++

Hi I am trying to convert a BSTR to String using W2A macro.

In the BSTR I have a data with an embedded NULL character.

Briefly my BSTR string looks like :

'X''\0','V','E','R'

The moment I try to get this value after conversion in a string and access string.C_str() I see unexpected characters in the framed string.

The string.C_str() yields me : X%

But same thing if I eliminate the '\0' character in "X\0VER" and just have "XVER". I get the correct value retained when I access string.C_str(). Any help appreciated.

Comment: `W2A` works with NUL-terminated strings (note how it doesn't take length as a parameter.) You should be getting `X` after conversion - I'm not sure how you are getting `X%`, show some code. In any case, these conversion macros can't deal with embedded NULs - the first one is assumed to terminate the string. You need something else - could use `_bstr_t`, or `CString`, or write your own conversion on top of `WideCharToMultiByte`.

Comment: Thanks. _bstr_t is not an option for me as I need the converted string in an UCHAR buffer. Could you suggest something else for my requirement plase ?

Comment: I have you three options. You discarded one. Two more to try.